# SAPUI5 Formatter array

Tags: sapui5

I am struggling to meet one specific requirement.

problem statement : In of the screen we are showing table with Edit button on each column. Problem is i want to enable this edit button only for the specific quarter. Right now its third quarter, so the months that fall in third and fourth quarter(6months  from AUG-JAN) should be enabled and rest(FEB-JUL) should be disabled. To achieve this i am using formatter, successfully able to disable first and second quarter month. Now my problem is I want to **disable August month once sep starts** and so on. How can i achieve this.?.ALso i want to optimize this code.

The months that falls under each quarter is different for the client that i am working for
Q1 months-- FEB--APR
Q2 months -- MAY-JUL
Q3 months --- AUG-OCT
Q4 months--- NOV-JAN

THank you in advance for all help

```
    var d = new Date();
         var n = d.getMonth();



         if(currentQuarter == "Q1" || currentQuarter=="Q2" ){
         months= ["JAN","FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN","JUL"
                ];

         if(parseInt(fiscalYear)==fullYear){

                if(budgetApproved === 'Unapproved' || budgetApproved === 'In-Progress'){



                    if (months[n]==value){
                        return true;
                    }


                        if(months.indexOf(value)<n ) {
                            return false;
                        }


                        if(months.indexOf(value)>n ){
                            return true;
                        }






                }

else {
        months = ["AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC","JAN"];

        if(parseInt(fiscalYear)==fullYear){

            if(budgetApproved === 'Unapproved' || budgetApproved === 'In-Progress'){





                if(months.indexOf(value) !==-1){
                    if(months.indexOf(value)<n ) {
                        return true;
                    }


                    if(months.indexOf(value)>n ){
                        return false;
                    }

                } else {
                    return false;
                }




            }
```

Comment: why do you want to disable Aug when Sept starts? Aug,Sept,Oct are in the same quarter. am I right?

Comment: yes thats true that it falls in same quarter. But once sep starts user should is not allowed to edit previous month(which will be Aug when sep starts and Aug , sep once oct starts so on) details even though it falls in same quarter. Its as per client requirement.